# Substitution $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{y(f(x)-f(0))}{y^2+x^2}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{(f(yu)-f(0))}{1+u^2}du$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> I need to find what was the substitution on the following integral:
>   $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{y(f(x)-f(0))}{y^2+x^2}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{(f(yu)-f(0))}{1+u^2}du$$

I tried $x=uy$ but it does not deliver the wanted result. I have no idea on how this substitution was done.

**Question:**

What was the substitution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think $x=uy$ works...

Comment: @See-WooLee              How do you get the 1 in the denominator?

Comment: @PedroGomes $y^2$ factors out from the denominator and on top you get $y^2$ (one already there times the one from the derivative) and these cancel.

Comment: @MultivaluedPersonality I do not believe how I did not see it. I am having a bad day. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @PedroGomes Nah, I constantly miss far more obvious things than this! :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = yu \implies dx = y du$, also $x = yu \implies u = x/y$ thus $ u \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $u \to +\infty$  as $x \to +\infty$.

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{y(f(x)-f(0))}{y^2+x^2}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^2(f(uy)-f(0))}{y^2+u^2y^2}du =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{(f(yu)-f(0))}{1+u^2}du$$